# Finding the cipher suites supported by a web server

Tags: webserver

So I need to find the cipher suites supported by a website. Now I can use this [NMap script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html) however this problem is research oriented so I need to write a code in order to collect the data automatically and parse it for research purposes.

Is there any library for C#, Java etc. that can do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure Thomas Pornin published a library like this written in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) has published a command line tool written in C# that does this, among other things. You can find the tool [here](https://github.com/pornin/TestSSLServer). You should be able to easily modify this into a library.